# Chart.js - Bar chart: Add text after numbers when h:over a Bar

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So, i'm using chart.js to draw some statistic bars.
When i h:hover a bar a popup will be shown with the detailed numbers.
Now i'd like to add text after this numer.
Like: 3958.08 /st
Or: 2989.71 /Kg

Is this possible?

[image]

**EDIT**
Just adding: multiTooltipTemplate: "<%=datasetLabels%> : <%=m2%>",
gave no result...

```
var elementM2 = {
    labels : ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","Maj","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dec"],
    datasets : [{
            label: "rosaAvf",
            multiTooltipTemplate: "<%=datasetLabels%> : <%=m2%>",
            fillColor: "rgba(193, 66, 66, 0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(193, 66, 66, 0.1)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)",
            data : [
                    thisYearJanRosaAvf,
```

Comment: yes! but you have to post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to use the optio multiTooltipTemplate

```
multiTooltipTemplate: "<%%=datasetLabel%> : <%%= value %>"
```

Please have a look [here](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/535#issuecomment-52075422)

Comment: You have to use like this : multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>"

Comment: I copied this exactly and it still not show anything after the numbers when i h:over...

Comment: Please add also this parameter relativeBars: true and look at this example: https://github.com/Regaddi/Chart.StackedBar.js/pull/49

Comment: also where i added it was important. No where in my code, but in the "new Chart" part..